# Como Exportar datos a excel según mes seleccionado?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo una exportación a excel, pero quiero que los datos sean exportados según el mes seleccionado, los meses los coloque en un select, pero al momento de exportar no me funciona y me da un error, adjunto código:

```
<select name="mes" id="mes">
<option value="8">Agosto</option>
<option value="9">Septiembre</option>
<option value="10">Octubre</option>
<option value="11">Noviembre</option>
<option value="12">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

código que manda a traer los datos:

```
public function getAllUsersExport($filter = array()){

$query = 'SELECT
    countries.sortname,
    users.*,
    pd.*,
    pa.paypal_email,
    up.firstname as under_affiliate

    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = users.Country
    LEFT JOIN users up ON up.id = users.refid
    LEFT JOIN payment_detail pd ON pd.payment_created_by = users.id
    LEFT JOIN paypal_accounts pa ON pa.user_id = users.id
    WHERE
        users.TYPE = "user" AND MONTH(users.created_at)= mes AND YEAR(users.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    ORDER BY users.id DESC
';

return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

}

Ese código no me funciona, pero si yo pongo: WHERE users.TYPE = "user" AND MONTH(users.created_at)= MONTH(NOW())AND YEAR(users.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())

si me hace la descarga, es decir, se descarga el mes actual con toda la información del mes presente, pero cuando pongo mes en lugar de MONTH(NOW()) no funciona, ya intente poner el mes así: 'mes' pero da error, lo coloque "mes" y hace la descarga pero sin datos a mostrar y con '$mes' también me da error, la exportación funciona con el mes actual, pero seleccionando meses no. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: y quien te dijo que la palabra 'mes' forma parte de las estructuras de control de mysql???

Comment: Como podría hacer para que lo pueda reconocer al momento de llamarlo en la base de datos? es decir, si selecciono agosto quiero que se guarde en la variable y al momento de hacer la consulta me lance datos de ese mes, soy nueva en esto y me voy guiando por tutoriales, estoy un poco perdida

Comment: primero que nada ya valistaste que el valor de select esta siendo recibido en php?

Comment: Estoy  bien perdida con esto, no hice validación, según yo al colocar MONTH(users.created_at)= mes este mandaba a llamar el mes que se selecciono en el select como haría la validación?

Comment: mira para programar tienes que hacer las cosas paso a paso no puedes saltar de A a F sin pasar por la B,C,D ... y hay una serie de preguntas que te tienes que hacer ... puedo imaginar que el codigo de lo han pasado y no sabes lo que tienes en las manos ...

Comment: Tu problema no es de SQL entonces, es de PHP y de cómo llevar las variables al SQL. Captura las variables por POST y luego trasladalas a la consulta, eso es algo básico en el aprendizaje de PHP. Voy a dejar mi respuesta por si te sirve de ayuda una vez hayas capturado el mes y año.

Comment: Revisa lo que es una *sentencia preparada*, según la extensión para MySQL que uses.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir un mes específico, necesitas también en qué año.

Si el campo `created_at` es DATE, DATETIME, o al menos VARCHAR yyyy-mm-dd, puedes usar [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para conseguir comparar la columna contra el formato de fecha deseado.

Por ejemplo, agosto-2022:

```
... AND DATE_FORMAT(users.created_at, '%Y-%m')='2022-08' ORDER BY users.id DESC;
```

[*] En el select html puedes colocar los `values` como `"08"`, `"09"` para hacer más fácil la concatenación con el año.

Comment: estoy casi seguro que no es es lo que quiere hacer ... observa el comentario que le hice ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 según su descripción del problema, está teniendo problemas al colocar el mes en distinta manera y es en esa parte que le estoy ayudando. Si es otra cosa, debe editar la pregunta y explicarse bien.

Comment: si vez indica que eesta intentando cambiar `'mes'` en lugar de `MONTH(NOW())` mes es un string o intenta usarlo como un metodo, no queda claro XD

Comment: Lo que quiero y según yo es que mes guarde el numero del mes que seleccione en el select, por ejemplo agosto es 8 entonces al seleccionar agosto y exportar, me exporte solo agosto, septiembre es 9 entonces que guarde el nueve y me arroje solo datos de septiembre, no se si me doy a entender.